# Pickadate in Angular directive setting today as default

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pickadate

I'm using Amsul's [Pickadate](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/) in a basic Angular directive:

```
.directive('pickadate', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            options: '=pickadate'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            // Extend the default options with passed ones
            var options = angular.extend({
                format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
            }, scope.options);

            // Set the picker
            element.pickadate(options);

            // Set the value
            scope.$parent.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(value) {
                if (!element.pickadate('picker')) return;
                element.pickadate('picker').set('select', value, {format: options.format});
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

In my template, I have:

```
<input id="dob" type="text" name="dob" ng-model="data.client.dob" pickadate />
```

And finally, my controller simply creates an empty client resource

```
$scope.data.client = new Client();
```

When the page loads, I want the fields to be blank, but instead, if I log the value in the directive, I get:

[image: 2]]

I'm almost certain this is a pickadate thing, but can't work out why today's date is being set. And the weird thing is, if I add `required` to the form field, it no longer sets today's date.

Comment: Please create a plunkr that demonstrates the problem